# Angular 2 Component test error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'TestComponentBuilder'

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular

I am trying to do Angular 2.0 Component tests. I was using [this](http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/testing-angular-2-components-unit-tests-testcomponentbuilder/) post as a reference (no reference in Angular 2.0 dos, yet).

This is my test:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import {
  it,
  describe,
  expect,
  inject,
  injectAsync,
  beforeEach,
  beforeEachProviders,
  TestComponentBuilder,
  ComponentFixture
} from 'angular2/testing';
import {Main} from './index';

describe('Main', () => {

  // provide our implementations or mocks to the dependency injector
  beforeEachProviders(() => [
    Main
  ]);

  it('should have title', inject([ Main ], (main) => {
    expect(main.title).toEqual('Hello Angular 2.0');
  }));

  it('should add item to list', injectAsync([TestComponentBuilder, Main], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder, main) => {
    return tcb.createAsync(Main).then((componentFixture: ComponentFixture) => {
      const element = componentFixture.nativeElement;
      expect(element.querySelectorAll('input').length).toBe(1);
    });
  }));
})
```

Now, I am getting an  `Cannot resolve all parameters for 'TestComponentBuilder'` error when running those tests. Trying to add `TestComponentBuilder` to the `beforeEachProviders` results with a different error:

`Cannot resolve all parameters for 'TestComponentBuilder'(?).`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set providers for testing this way:

```
(...)

import {setBaseTestProviders} from 'angular2/testing';

import {
  TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,
  TEST_BROWSER_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS
} from 'angular2/platform/testing/browser';

describe('Test suite', () => {
  setBaseTestProviders(TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,
                    TEST_BROWSER_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS);

  beforeEach(() => {
    (...)
  });

  (...)
});
```

Here is a sample plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/oVBPsH?p=preview.

Comment: Already tried this -  getting an error: `Cannot resolve all parameters for 'ResolvedMetadataCache'(?, ?)`

Comment: Which version of Angular2 do you use?

Comment: Beta13. Is it related?

Comment: I don't think so. It should work with this version... I added a sample plunkr in my answer.